# Raspberry Pi Zero W as USB Keyboard

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-zero, pi-zero-w, raspbian-jessie

I’m having trouble setting this up on my Raspberry Pi Zero W.

I am getting the error that there is no file called 'hidg0'? When I look in dev/ I do not see one either? I am running on the latest software.

I have followed all the steps of this tutorial: https://gndtovcc.home.blog/2020/04/17/turn-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-keyboard-hid/comment-page-1/?unapproved=2230&moderation-hash=d27b7e989bba4b3da280bd07435d85b6#comment-2230

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
NULL_CHAR = chr(0)
 
def write_report(report):
    try:
        with open('/dev/hidg0', 'rb+') as fd:
            fd.write(report.encode())
    except: pass
 
# Press a
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)
# Release keys
write_report(NULL_CHAR*8)
# Press SHIFT + a = A
write_report(chr(32)+NULL_CHAR+chr(4)+NULL_CHAR*5)
 
# Press b
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)
# Release keys
write_report(NULL_CHAR*8)
# Press SHIFT + b = B
write_report(chr(32)+NULL_CHAR+chr(5)+NULL_CHAR*5)
 
# Press SPACE key
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(44)+NULL_CHAR*5)
 
# Press c key
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(6)+NULL_CHAR*5)
# Press d key
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(7)+NULL_CHAR*5)
 
# Press RETURN/ENTER key
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(40)+NULL_CHAR*5)
 
# Press e key
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(8)+NULL_CHAR*5)
# Press f key
write_report(NULL_CHAR*2+chr(9)+NULL_CHAR*5)
 
# Release all keys
write_report(NULL_CHAR*8)
```

Does someone have any idea?

Edit:

Sorry for not giving good information for my question, will do it next time. For now, on another Pi it did work. I am going to put that SD card content in mine and test it.

Comment: please add the complete error message ... copy and paste into the question ... do **not** paste into comments

Comment: How did you see the error? `except: pass` would hide the error message - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice  Check the files (config / modules) etc and the chmod +x are done correctly.  Can you also post your /usr/bin/isticktoit_usb as code here.

Answer (score 1):

Add some error checking to your scripts. I would specifically check for `libcomposite` module to be present in the kernel, no other gadget drivers loaded (`lsmod | grep g_` gives no output), `configfs` is mounted and one and only one UDC file exists in `/sys/class/udc` before you bind the driver.

Printing errors from your Python code would also help:

```
except, e:
    print('Error: '+ str(e))
```